# Change form location using nlua

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, lua, nlua

I'm writing a simple program in c# using .net framework 4.8, winforms, and nlua. I want to change the location of my main form using a lua script. Here is what I tried:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

```
using NLua;

lua_context = new Lua();
lua_context.LoadCLRPackage();
lua_context.DoString("import 'System.Drawing'");
lua_context.DoString("import 'System.Windows.Forms'");

MainForm main_form = new MainForm();
lua_context["main_form"] = main_form;
lua_context.DoString("main_form.Location = Point(5, 5)");
```

I get this error when calling the last line:

> Exception thrown: 'NLua.Exceptions.LuaScriptException' in NLua.dll
> An unhandled exception of type 'NLua.Exceptions.LuaScriptException' occurred in NLua.dll
> [string "chunk"]:1: attempt to call a nil value (global 'Point')

I have also tried:

```
lua_context.DoString("main_form.Location = System.Drawing.Point(5, 5)");
```

and I get this error:

> Exception thrown: 'NLua.Exceptions.LuaScriptException' in NLua.dll
> An unhandled exception of type 'NLua.Exceptions.LuaScriptException' occurred in NLua.dll
> [string "chunk"]:1: attempt to index a nil value (global 'System')

Comment: It should be `main_form.Location = new Point(5, 5)`. But I don't know how NLua works, hence if you should pass an already constructed Point object or if declaring a `new Point()` in the string itself is enough, or even if you need to fully qualify the assembly, as in `... new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5)`.

Comment: Just change x and y explicitly `main_form.Location.X = 5` and `main_form.Location.Y = 5`

Comment: @Jimi, There is no new keyword in lua. The way to create a new object (as far as I understand) is to do it like I'm doing already.

Comment: @Nifim, I tried that as well. I don't get an error, but for some reason it doesn't work. Besides that this problem I have with Point also happens with a few other things, so I really need to find the root issue.

Comment: Well, you have this: `MainForm main_form = new MainForm();`. Can you do the same thing with a Point? I.e., just assign the Point value, as you're *assigning* the Form instance (`lua_context["main_form"] = main_form;`)?

Comment: No. That is not a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

`import("System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")`

The [form.lua](https://github.com/NLua/NLua/blob/main/extras/examples/form.lua#L5) used to work

Comment: I see. So I need both `import("System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")` and `import("System.Drawing")`. This works! Do you know why the more verbose import is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

There is no global `Point` in Lua.
Maybe you can use `System.Drawing.Point(5, 5)`.

Alternatively adding `lua_context.DoString("import 'System.Drawing'");`  should fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I tried ```lua_context.DoString("main_form.Location = System.Drawing.Point(5, 5)");``` and I get the same error: "NLua.Exceptions.LuaScriptException: '[string "chunk"]:1: attempt to index a nil value (global 'System')'". I have already imported system.drawing in the lua context.